# Using pip and pip3 and getting too many modules

Tags: python, pip

I'm sorry if my question is too basic, I'm just getting started using Python.
My problem is that through all the learning process I've installed a lot of modules using pip and pip3. But now when I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` it shows me more modules than I have installed in that directory, so I guess the modules get installed on the machine. I mistake on using the `pip install --user` option. Is there a way so I can get rid of all those modules and start all over again as I forgot all the modules I've installed?

Thanks for the help

Comment: That what virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper are for: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ They will help you seperate all the libs for the different things you are working on.

Comment: I understand. But is there a way I can start over again and not having everything installed on the machine? or you are suggesting I should just start using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper from now?

Comment: You should use it from now on. If you need a clean environment, there is a parameter for it. Read the full document and you will get the idea.